# Centering a table that spans in two column document

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table that spans in two-column document.
The issue is that the table is not center aligned with my `\centering` command. Futhermore, the table is not fit into the document with 10pt fonts.

How to solve these issues?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

{\centering
\begin{table*}[!hbt]
\caption{hello core APIs}\label{tab:apis}
{\small\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}

\toprule

     {\bf API group} & {\bf Name} & {\bf Parameters} & {\bf output} \\
     \midrule\midrule[.1em]

     \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Creation} 
         & {\tt createFBFSummary}
         & {\tt summary}, {\tt tableWidth}%, {\tt schema} (optional)  
         & FBF summary \\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
         & {\tt createLabeledSummary}
         & {\tt summary}
         & Labeled summary \\

\midrule[.1em] 

\multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Query} 
    & {\tt query}
    & {\tt summary}, {\tt label}
    & value \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    & {\tt search}
    & {\tt directory}, {\tt label}
    & (summary, value) pairs \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: all the answers have good points, but the most important one isn't really highlighted.  that is, the `table` environment *floats*, so adding any kind of center instruction outside its scope won't affect the position of the table at all.  start by moving `\centering` *inside* the `table` environment, and get rid of the now-useless braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *switch* `\centering` is only enforced when it finds the end of a paragraph (an explicit `\par` or a blank line). Since you're wrapping `\centering` inside a group and there is no such "end of paragraph" signal before the group closes, the effect of `\centering` is never enforced.

The solution is to remove the scoping braces `{`...`}` since they're not needed here (despite using `\small` as well). Alternatively, use `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}`, which will insert additional spacing above/below the `tabular`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[t]
  \caption{hello core APIs}
  \small\centering
  \begin{tabular}{llll}

    \toprule

    {\bfseries API group} & {\bfseries Name} & {\bfseries Parameters} & {\bfseries output} \\
    \midrule\midrule[.1em]

    \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Creation} 
      & {\ttfamily createFBFSummary}
      & {\ttfamily summary}, {\ttfamily tableWidth}%, {\ttfamily schema} (optional)  
      & FBF summary \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
      & {\ttfamily createLabeledSummary}
      & {\ttfamily summary}
      & Labeled summary \\

    \midrule[.1em] 

    \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Query} 
      & {\ttfamily query}
      & {\ttfamily summary}, {\ttfamily label}
      & value \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
      & {\ttfamily search}
      & {\ttfamily directory}, {\ttfamily label}
      & (summary, value) pairs \\   
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

In the above example, the end of the `table*` environment constitutes an "end of paragraph" signal.

Answer (score 5):

Some additional suggestions (beyond removing the scope-limiting curly braces), in no particular order:

- Use a `p` column type (of width 3.5cm); get rid of the `\multicolumn` statements
- Set up a new column type (called `t`  in the code below) for the fixed-width font material in columns 2 and 3; get rid of the individual `\tt` directives
- It's not necessary to invoke `\small`; just typeset the table at the normal document font size
- Since you're using the macros of the `booktabs` package, do embrace the package's overall approach to designing tables as well. E.g., use horizontal rules sparingly, and use whitespace instead. The result will be a more "open" looking table.
- Don't use the deprecated font switching macros `\tt` and `\bf`; instead, use `\ttfamily` and `\bfseries`.
- The elements `h` and `b` in the placement directive `[!hbt]` have absolutely no effect on a `table*` environment. The omissing of the `p` element is potentially problematic as it prevents the creation of a full-page float and thereby increases the chances that the float will end up at the very end of the document. My advice would be to omit the `[!hbt]` directive entirely.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\newcolumntype{t}{>{\ttfamily}l}  % automatic-ttfamily "l" column

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{table*}
\caption[hello core APIs]{hello core APIs\strut}\label{tab:apis}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{3.5cm} t t l @{}}
\toprule
\bfseries API group & \bfseries\rmfamily Name & \bfseries\rmfamily Parameters & \bfseries output \\
\midrule
Creation
& createFBFSummary  & summary, tableWidth & FBF summary \\
& createLabeledSummary & summary & Labeled summary \\
\addlinespace
Query               & query & summary, label & value \\
& search & directory, label & (summary, value) pairs \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[4-13]
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer although `[!hbt]` does have an effect it is same as `[t]` so prevents float pages and increases the chance of the float going to the end of the document. The advice not to use it is good though:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for this point; I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given up to now fix the problem, but go wrong in suggesting “improvements”.

About the main problem, just for completeness:

1. `\centering` outside the `table` environment doesn't affect the environment at all
2. `{\centering...}` has no effect, because the paragraph ends after `}` is scanned, so `\centering` has already ended its action.

So the format should be

```
\lipsum

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering\small

\caption{hello core APIs}\label{tab:apis}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
[...]
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\lipsum
```

I prefer to have the formatting instructions at the top; they don't affect the caption anyway.

Now, let's consider the tabular and how it can be improved.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\keyw}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}
\small\centering

\caption{hello core APIs}\label{tab:apis}

\medskip % not necessary if you load caption

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
% header
\bfseries API group & \bfseries Name & \bfseries Parameters & \bfseries output \\
% table data
\midrule
Creation
  & \keyw{createFBFSummary}
  & \keyw{summary}, \keyw{tableWidth}%, \keyw{schema} (optional)  
  & FBF summary \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  & \keyw{createLabeledSummary}
  & \keyw{summary}
  & Labeled summary \\
\midrule
Query
  & \keyw{query}
  & \keyw{summary}, \keyw{label}
  & value \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  & \keyw{search}
  & \keyw{directory}, \keyw{label}
  & (summary, value) pairs \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Note the personal command for typesetting special words in typewriter type; also `\bf` and `\tt` should never be used. Nor double horizontal rules. There's also no need for `\multirow`: the word "Creation" automatically refers to the blank cell below it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `center` environment instead of centering ; but I don't know why

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[!hbt]
  \caption{hello core APIs}\label{tab:apis}
  \small
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}

      \toprule

      {\bf API group} & {\bf Name} & {\bf Parameters} & {\bf output} \\
      \midrule\midrule[.1em]

      \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Creation} 
                      & {\tt createFBFSummary}
                                   & {\tt summary}, {\tt tableWidth}%, {\tt schema} (optional)  
                                                      & FBF summary \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                      & {\tt createLabeledSummary}
                                   & {\tt summary}
                                                      & Labeled summary \\

      \midrule[.1em] 

      \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{Query} 
                      & {\tt query}
                                   & {\tt summary}, {\tt label}
                                                      & value \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
                      & {\tt search}
                                   & {\tt directory}, {\tt label}
                                                      & (summary, value) pairs \\   
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table*}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the usual advice is not to use `center` in tables as it adds vertical space and more vertical space is added around the float so you get extra large space.